# reopening created windows form application from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

how to reopen a created visual studio project? 
when i reopen a created project in visual studio (by double clicking .csproj) the GUI 
(i made windows form application) is not appearing, why?

Comment: Double-click the form in the Solution Explorer window to open the designer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file that contains the **.sln** extension, **not your .csproj** file because that will open just one project, not the entire solution.

you can understand it like this:

csproj = C Sharp Project;
sln = solution

Answer (score 0):

Just to state the obvious too:

View > Solution Explorer > Program.cs